# unknown chip on pcb

Tags: integrated-circuit, pcb

Can someone help me identify this chip? The first row is 1647HC. Second row 4069UBF. Tird DB1354. I can't identify the manufacturer logo.

I'm new at this.

[image]

Comment: I’d try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The markings suggest that it's an unbuffered 4069 (hex-inverter.)  The PCB layout for pins 7 and 14 would support this too.

Comment: @IanCook while short, this may well qualify as an answer in its own right. If you add the "source" of your information (be it your own experience or links to sites where these markings can be found and searched), it would probably also help. Or in your case the comparison to a well-established pattern (the PCB layout of the pins you mention). I've variously stumbled over this problem and always found it useful when folks shared _their_ favorite sources of information. It's like peeking into the "tool chest" of another fellow reverse engineer or developer 

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks, I didn't think it worth while as a simple google search is quite revealing. However, I've added an answer now explaining a bit more of the thought process and corroboratory evidence.

Comment: @IanCook The problem with web searches is: what am I looking for and what do I feed into the search engine? So thanks for taking the time to answer. This is great!

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 'classic' series of logic ICs that are widely used.  These are the [7400 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits) and [4000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4000-series_integrated_circuits).

The 2nd number on your chip, 4069, screamed at me 4000-series.
Looking up 4069 in the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4000-series_integrated_circuits#Parts_list) shows it's a hex inverter. For the 4000-series a UB suffix means unbuffered. The final F suffix likely means ceramic packaging.

It's then essential to check the number of pins.  A 4069 has 14 pins (6 inputs, 6 outputs, Vdd and Gnd.) This matches your chip.

Moving on the pinout, a google search for "[4069 pinout](https://www.google.com/search?q=4069%20pinout)" shows that pin 14 (bottom left in your image) is Vdd and pin 7 (top right) Gnd. The PCB traces for these pins are routed quite differently to the other pins and pin 14 connects to a much wider trace. This is consistent with it being a power supply pin.

Whilst you've shared little of the surrounding area, it's possible to see than pins 2 & 3 are connected as are pins 4 & 5. Looking at the pinout of a 4069 this would mean than 3 of the inverters are daisy-chained together.  Again, a google image search for "[4069 schematic](https://www.google.com/search?q=4069%20schematic)" reveal an number of circuits where inverters are connected this way. This supports the plausibility of your chip being a 4069.

Overall, the available evidence suggests the chip is a 4069 hex inverter.  A wider view of the PCB and surrounding components would help to increase the certainty.

---

The other markings are likely to be manufacturer specific and include date or batch codes.  The following [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520680/what-are-the-tools-to-identify-ics-by-marking) on [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) explains more details about markings and issues with interpreting them.

Comment: ian that is Great second coming i would add  that to +1